# Angular 2 form, get method istead of post

Tags: forms, angular, submit

While working on Angular 2 form submit I run into a problem. When I create an object inside a component everything works well and my form gets submit via post method. But when I am using an object from a class outside the component my form sends a get request with url http://localhost:4200/blog?title=sss&content=ssssss

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Template:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
   <!-- <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Tytuł</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="title" rows="1"
                  ngModel name = "title" required minlength="3" #title="ngModel"></textarea>
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!title.valid && title.touched">Wprowadzono za krótki tekst (minum to 3 znaki).</span>
        <label for="content">Zawartość:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="content" rows="3"
                  ngModel name = "content" required minlength="3" #content="ngModel"></textarea>
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!content.valid && content.touched">Wprowadzono za krótki tekst (minum to 3 znaki).</span>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
              [disabled] ="!f.valid"
      >Wyślij</button>
    </form>
```

Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";
import {Blog} from "../../shared/blog";
import {BlogService} from "../../services/blog.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-form',
  templateUrl: './blog-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-form.component.css']
})
export class BlogFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('f') form: NgForm;
  errorMessage: string;
/* this works well
blog = {
    title: '',
    content: '',
    dateCreated: ''
  }*/

//this doesn't work
blog: Blog;

  ngOnInit(){}

  onSubmit(){
    this.blog.title = this.form.value.title;
    this.blog.content = this.form.value.content;
  }
}
```

The Blog class. I tried both this:

```
export class Blog {
  constructor(public title = '', public content = '', public dateCreated = ''){}}
```

And this:

```
export class Blog {
  constructor(public title : string, public content : string, public dateCreated : string){}}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Can you provide the service you have created?

Comment: I am not using the service. It's just the old import there

Comment: The issue remains if I remove the import

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is happening but try not using `this.form.value`.

```
onSubmit(){
  this.blog.title = this.form.title;
  this.blog.content = this.form.content;
  console.log(this.blog);
}
```

Use of value posts back your page. Now this code should work.

Comment: I get an error than: property 'title' does not exist on type 'NgForm'